# Getting First Row from all Record - Sql

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains

```
Reg_Num    Name       Cash        Date

1          John       500        2011-2-12
1          lisak      600        2011-2-12
1          Joe        300        2011-2-11
2          Josh       700        2011-2-10
2          Mark       200        2011-2-12
```

now I want the output as First record from every Reg_Num
output:

```
1          John        500       2011-2-12
2          JOsh        700       2011-2-10
```

Thank You

Comment: "First" as ordered by **what** ??

Comment: If you find an answr that solves your problem you SHOULD mark it as accepted so that others need not try to answer it again, Leaving it open is rude to the one answering and also clutters stackoverflow with open questions that are actually answered!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
;with cteMinDate as (
    select Reg_Num, Name, Cash, Date,
           row_number() over (partition by Reg_Num order by Date) as RowNum
        from YourTable
)
select Reg_Num, Name, Cash, Date
    from cteMinDate
    where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: @Paramahamsa: Was my answer helpful? If so, please consider accepting it. If not, you should post your solution as an answer for others to see.